# Change this stored procedure to avoid using CROSS APPLY?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, northwind

I am trying to show the names of the bosses and their employees in charge in different columns.

I was able to do it with cross apply, but I was asked to do it without using it, but I can't really think out on how to do it.

I am using the Northwind database for SQL Server and this is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getBossAndEmployeeNames
    @bossID NCHAR(5)
AS
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_BOSSES_AND_EMPLOYEES
    (
        BossFullName VARCHAR(35), 
        EmployeeFullName VARCHAR(35)
    )

    INSERT INTO #TEMP_BOSSES_AND_EMPLOYEES
    SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as BossFullName, sub.EmployeeFullName 
    FROM Employees 
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as EmployeeFullName FROM Employees WHERE ReportsTo = @bossID 
    ) AS sub
    WHERE EmployeeID = @bossID 

    SELECT * FROM #TEMP_BOSSES_AND_EMPLOYEES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT B.FirstName + ' ' + B.LastName AS BossFullName
    , E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS EmployeeFullName
FROM dbo.Employees B
INNER JOIN dbo.Employees E ON E.ReportsTo = B.id
WHERE B.EmployeeID = @bossID;
```

You don't even need a temp table as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you so much, the temp tables were just to accomplish what I was asked to do, but INNER JOIN did the job!